# Is there a way to run scala code in the ipython notebook?

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook

I know there is the script magics in the ipython notebook for running code in other languages. See for example http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/github.com/ipython/ipython/raw/master/examples/notebooks/Script%20Magics.ipynb.

And I know you can run Scala in script mode. See, for example http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/166.

But I couldn't figure out if there was a way to get the ipython notebook to run scala code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second google answer for "Ipython scala" search yield [IScala notebook announce](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/IScala-a-Scala-language-backend-for-IPython-td5031365.html).

Answer (score 4):

OP has asked about running scala code in the ipython notebook, not if there's an ipython equivalent for scala. he is aware he can run it with magics as any other script.

a better answer, though still not what OP has asked, is a project for running scala in the similar fashion of notebooks in a web page https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook

Comment: the IScala backend is exactly that.  It lets you run scala code in a IPython notebook.